# correct encoding for json in rest service for iOS app

Tags: php, json, rest

I'm trying to create a small proof of concept webservice in PHP. Its a counter for a website page.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE rootwebsite.visitor_count SET visitorCount=visitorCount+1");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from rootwebsite.visitor_count");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $row['visitorCount'];


echo json_encode($row['visitorCount']);
```

My doubt comes while encoding for JSON. 
Finally I need is a REST service to provide data for iOS app. Above code gives result as:

`"15"`

First, I need help with the ideal json format. Is it supposed to be

```
{visitorCount, 15}
```

Secondly, I need help regarding how to achieve that in my php code. I'm still working on this part yet, but first one needed to be answered first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"15"
```

...is valid JSON.

```
{visitorCount, 15}
```

...is not valid JSON. You probably meant:

```
{"visitorCount": 15}
```

When you `echo json_encode($row['visitorCount']);`, you're encoding and echoing the value of row['visitorCount']. In order to encode & echo the array, do `echo json_encode($row);`

If there are any other keys you don't want echo'ed, clear them with `unset($row['id'])`